# OpenGL:How to make "Feet" go up and down?

Tags: c++, opengl, if-statement, case, translation

I'm writing code that draws a polygon and gives it two feet, walks from the right until it gets to the middle, does a flip, and then lands and walks to the left. I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to animate his feet. All I want to do is make one go up, then come down, then the other go up, and then come down. I know all I have to do is change the Y values of his feet, but I can't figure out how.

My professor talks about key frames a lot, but wouldn't every step that my "Polyman" would take be a key frame leading to infinite amount of cases? Here is my timer function...

```
void TimerFunction(int value)  //float plx = 7.0, ply=-3.0, linet=0.00;
{
switch(frame)
{
case 1:
    dx-=0.15;
    plx-=0.15;    //dx=polygon, plx = one foot, pl2x = other foot
    pl2x-=0.15;
    if(dx<=0.0)
        {
            plx=0.0;  //this case makes polyman walk to the middle 
            dx=0.0;
            pl2x=0.0;
            frame=2;
        }
    break;

case 2:
    dxt+=0.05;
    if (dxt<=-0.00)   //this is a triangle I translate over polyman appearing as if he's opening his mouth
    {
        dxt=0.00;
        frame=3;
    }
    break;
case 3:
    dy+=0.2;
    theta+=10.0;
    thetat+=10.0;
    dyt+=0.2; //this is the flip with polyman's mouth open
    ply+=0.2;
    pl2y+=0.2;
    linet2+=10.0;
    linet+=10.0;
    if(dy>5.0 || theta>360.00)
    {
        dy=5.0;
        dyt=5.0;
        ply=5.0;
        pl2y=5.0;
        linet2=0.0;
        theta=0.0;
        thetat=0.0;
        linet=0.0;
        frame=4;
    }
    break;
case 4:
    dy-=0.2;
    dyt-=0.2;
    ply-=0.2;
    pl2y-=0.2;
        if(dy<=-3.0)  //this is polyman coming back down to earth
        {
            dy=-3.0;
            dyt=-3.0;
            ply=-3.0;
            pl2y=-3.0;
            frame=5;
        }
        break;
case 5:
    dxt-=0.2;
    if (dxt<-3)
    {                             //this is the triangle slowly translating left appearing as if he's closing his mouth
        dxt-=3.0;
    }
    if (dxt<=-8)
    {
        dxt = -8;
        frame = 6;
    }       
    break;
case 6:
    dx-= 0.15;
    plx-= 0.15;
    pl2x-=0.15; //this is polyman walking off the stage to the left
    if(dx<=-8.0)
    {
        dx=-8.0;
        plx=-8.0;
        pl2x=-8.0;
    }
    break;



}

glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(30, TimerFunction, 1);
}
```

All variables that are used in my timerfunction are global. Thanks for your time! If you need any more of my code just ask and i'll append.

Comment: Imagine a keyframe as a special point on the timeline. So if the step takes 1 second, you might have kf at time=0, time=.5, and time=1.Then your job is to interpolate the position based on where you are in the timeline.

Comment: Johnny Mopp, I appreciate the response man, but you just confused me even more, could you explain a bit?

Comment: vary ply and pl2y in the cases where he's walking.

but you want to vary them alternately, and alternate how you vary them. so you need another parameter besides frame (which doesn't really mean frame here, but more like mode or interval, but that's a different problem).

then when it switches to the next "frame" you need to reset the feet to the normal position, or let them continue varying, depending on whether the new "frame" is a walking mode.